# WM6 Sockets using GPRS

Tags: c#, sockets, windows-mobile, network-programming, gprs

I am writing at NTRIP client on WM6. Basically I am getting data from a server using sockets by first sending a configuration. But I am unable to get it working over a GPRS connection on the same device.

I send this message.

```
Get / HTTP/1.0
User-Agent: NTRIP client
Accept: */*
Connection: close
```

To this server.

```
Hostname: mamba.gps.caltech.edu
Port: 2101
```

I make the connection by doing this

```
string message = "GET / HTTP/1.0\r\nUser-Agent: NTRIP client\r\nAccept: */*\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n"
IPAddress ipAddress = Dns.GetHostEntry(hostname).AddressList[0];

_NTRIPCaster = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
_NTRIPCaster.Connect(new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, Convert.ToInt32(port)));
_NTRIPCaster.Send(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message));
for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) //Wait for upto 5 seconds for a response
{
     Thread.Sleep(100);
     if (_NTRIPCaster.Available > 0)
     {
           Byte[] inBytes = new byte[_NTRIPCaster.Available];
           _NTRIPCaster.Receive(inBytes);
           sourceTable += Encoding.ASCII.GetString(inBytes, 0, inBytes.Length);
           //Check if all of the Source table has been recieved
           if (sourceTable.Contains("ENDSOURCETABLE")) 
           {
                 sourceTableRecieved = true;
                 break;
           }
      }
}
```

This all works fine if I have a Wi-Fi connection, or the device is docked to a PC and active sync is sharing the PCs internet connection.

If I cut off the internet on the PC, and disable the Wi-Fi then its unable to resolve the hostname to an IP address. Doesn't even get to the socket connections. Basically it is not using the modem in the device and making use of a GPRS connection. This happens whether the GPRS is connected or not.

Since I am on WM6, I have looked at the connection manager API - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa458120 .

But after following a few other posts I have been able to find on stackoverflow and other forums I have been unable to get it to work. Does anyone know how I can make a GPRS connection and start sending data to a server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After alot of experimenting I got it to work.

Used the ConnectionManager, in SDF from OpenNetCF

```
  ConnectionManager connectionManager = new ConnectionManager();
  connectionManager.Connect(false);
  Thread.Sleep(50); //Give it time to make a connection
```

Next, I used the TCP/IP method of connection. Honestly, I am not sure how this differs to sockets with a TCP protocol, as from what I can tell a TCPClient object, has a property called Client which itself is a socket. Stripped down sample of code below.

```
       using (NetworkStream ns = _client.GetStream())
       using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
       {
           ns.Write(messageBytes, 0, messageBytes.Length);
           for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
           {
               Thread.Sleep(20);
               byte[] buffer = new byte[16 * 1024];
               int bytes;
               while ((bytes = ns.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
               {
                   ms.Write(buffer, 0, bytes);
               }
               byte[] data = ms.ToArray();
               response += Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, data.Length);
           }
```

I am now getting data sent and received as expected.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the higher level network objects like the HttpRequest then the connection manager API is automatically invoked by the .NET Framework.  Is there a reason you are using low-level sockets?

Comment: I've too heard that HttpRequest manages this for you, which would be nice. I've never tried to access it with a HttpRequest, as every example I could find on NTRIP used socket connections. NTRIP has its own protocol. I have to maintain a continuous connection to the server as I stream data from it until I or the server choose to drop the connection. I'll be honest and say this is the first time I've had to use sockets.

Comment: I'm not familair with the NTRIP protocol, but what your code sample looks like HTTP.  If NTRIP piggy-backs over HTTP then you might still be able to use the HttpReqest object.  Just a thought...

Comment: In any case, there are a bunch of samples on the net.  Here's one that looks simple enough: [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/anthonywong/archive/2006/03/13/550686.aspx)

Comment: Ill try using it tomorrow, but I have a feeling it won't work. I developed the app on the PC before porting to the mobile, so it should be easy to drop in a http request instead. I believe I may need TCP connection rather than a HttpRequest because after I make a request I receive a constant stream of data back. Its just a guess :) p.s. NTRIP is a protocol used to stream correctional data into a GNSS (GPS) receiver to improve the accuracy.

Comment: httprequest failed, as the answer back from the server is not a http response, so i get a procotol exception.

Comment: I guess you will have to use ConnectionManager then.  Take a look at the link I posted that has a sample of C# code that uses ConnectionManager.  I looks straightforward.

Comment: I did try to PInvoke those commands, and have tried the sample code. Unfortuntatly it didn't work, but thanks for trying. So i've spoken to the manufacturer of the device and am awaiting a reply. There original answer is using a WWAN (mobile phone) is not the same as 802.11 (Wi-Fi), WWAn uses TCP/IP over PPP. Not sure how that differs to WiFi though.